# Why does government ban things that have not been scientifically proven to harm us?

Tags: india, social-policy

A High Court bench of my country, on Oct 24, 2018, passed a law that asks telecom providers to block all pornographic websites.

The 1961 international treaty, *Single Convention on Narcotic Drugs*, classed cannabis as a hard drug thus our government, again, banned its sale and trade.

Both of these have no proven harmful effect on us(Unlike Cigarettes) and have a huge potential market (Especially cannabis as the Export can generate a tremendous income), at the same time, the sale of the same in the black market reduces government revenue and opens the door to a lot of criminal activity.

So, why (What political Agenda?) not take an example of other countries (US, Canada, etc.) and remove the imposed bans?

In this case, the mentioned Country is India.

Comment: It's the same reason why governments want to kill jews, gays, etc.. To please some bigots and hence got votes.

Comment: You should provide a source for your claim that "cannabis [...] have no harmful effect on us". There are plenty of sources stating the opposite.

Comment: "Scientifically Proven" is an oxymoron, science is inductive. please change to "Demonstrated" or "Confirmed".

Comment: There _are_ ill effects from pornography; on teen's socialization, on sex addicts, on human trafficking, on the perception of women, etc. I'm not saying it's bad, but nothing's perfect.

Comment: @Guran There are probably even more sources stating that cannabis is not very dangerous. This could be actually a question for some medicine stackexchange. I've heard the problem is the increasing THC concentration in modern cannabis products which may have greater harmful effects.

Comment: Why does the USA bans kinder eggs ?

Comment: @Max The US didn't really ban kinder eggs directly. It's more of a side effect of another ruling from long time ago.

Comment: @dandavis: There may be effects of pornography.  (After all, everything has effects, no?)  Whether or not these are ILL effects is pretty much a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Trilarion ”Not very dangerous” is hardly the same as “no proven harmful effect”. THC certainly *has* harmful effects. What may be up for debate is whether it’s more or less harmful than legal drugs like tobacco and alcohol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Governments all over the world impose all sorts of policies and do not actually go with science many times.

The distribution of [pornography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornography_by_region) is restricted in many regions, as well as the [selling of drugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibition_of_drugs#Penalties). On the other hand global warming is practically proven scientifically but many governments do not give a toss about it.

In the end it's a mix of religious, ethical, morale and practical considerations that let the public opinion (in case of democracies) or in general the current rulers come to the decision to ban something.

While science can be an important input to politics, there is no mandatory connection between politics and science. Still, science can help change the public opinion, mostly by educating it about the true facts and relationships.

The supporters of the current ruling party/parties in India seem to believe that consuming pornography or consuming cannabis is not desired behavior while in Canada or the US the voters seem to think differently.

A public campaign supported by scientific arguments might be able to change the opinion of the voters in India in the future. But that's far from sure.